# How can I create a new object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have a component and in that component I toggle a boolean variable, in order to show and a hide a menu when an image is clicked.

The html looks like this:

```
<img src="../../assets/image/dropdown.png" class="dropdown-image" (click)="toggleDropDownMenu()">
        <div class="dropdown-content" [hidden]="dropDownMenu">
            <a class="menu-item" (click)="showTerms()">Policy</a>
            <a class="menu-item" (click)="showProfile()">Profile</a>
            <a class="menu-item" (click)="logOut()">Log Out</a>
        </div>
```

The toggleDropdownMenu() is the following:

```
public toggleDropDownMenu(): void {
    this.dropDownMenu = !this.dropDownMenu;    
  }
```

So when I click the button I can show and hide the menu options.

What I want to achive further is to hide the menu, also when the user clicks outside the menu element. After some searching, I came across the concept of a directive.. I implemented this idea in the following way:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if(this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      console.log("clicked inside");
    } else {
      console.log("clicked outside");
    }
  }

  constructor(private eRef: ElementRef) {
    console.log(" not clicked");
  }
}
```

Which works, in the sense that I get the right messages in the console when I click inside or outside the element. What I want to do though, is to be able to write something like this on my html:

```
    <img src="../../assets/image/dropdown.png" class="dropdown-image" (click)="toggleDropDownMenu()" 
(clickOutside)="closeMenu()">
            <div class="dropdown-content" [hidden]="dropDownMenu">
                <a class="menu-item" (click)="showTerms()">Policy</a>
                <a class="menu-item" (click)="showProfile()">Profile</a>
                <a class="menu-item" (click)="logOut()">Log Out</a>
            </div>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Is there an example?

Comment: You want to call a public method on the component, from the directive? Or call a directive's method from the component?

Comment: When you use the (click) directive, you can call a function that is executed when you click. The directive I have now, just logs in the console if the user clicks in or out. What I would ideally like to do is if the user clicks outside create a function in my component and call it, using something like (clickOutside)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by 'know what are the parameters of the constructo", but for capturing click events and check if the event is inside your component you can do the following :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ab-some-component',
  templateUrl: './some-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-component.scss'],
  host: {
    '(document:click)': 'documentClickListener($event)',
  },    
})

export class SomeComponent{

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  /**
   * Listen for document click event.
   * Check's if a click outside of this element
   */
  documentClickListener(event): void {
    if (!this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target))
      //Click event occur outside of this component bounds.
  }

}
```

Basically what we are doing here is declaring at the host level a document click event listener and assign in to local component function. 
Then check if the element ref (That was injected at the constructor) containing the click event target.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I am new to angular and I am not sure how things work. On the html, you can add to an element (click)="doSomething()" and when you click on that element what you have in the doSomething, happens. I want to do the same for when the user clicks outside. At the moment I can print at the console if the user clicked inside or outside from the element. The console log is done from the directive. What I would like to have is a way to call a function declared in the component, like (clickOutside)=''doSomethingElse()".

Comment: There is no clickOutside callback as far as I know... I think that the best in this situation is to declare a Boolean flag , toggle it on when doSometging() triggered and then in the documentClickListener() check if the Boolean is true. Another option is to declare new document click listener on every doSometging(), But then you also need to manage the listener unsubscribe function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using @Output EventEmitters

```
//directive.ts
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {

  @Output() clickInside:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() clickOutside:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if(this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      console.log("clicked inside");
      this.clickInside.emit(null);
    } else {
      console.log("clicked outside");
      this.clickOutside.emit(null);
    }
  }

  constructor(private eRef: ElementRef) {
    console.log(" not clicked");
  }
}
```

And then in your component

```
<img src="../../assets/image/dropdown.png" class="dropdown-image" 
(clickInside)="toggleDropDownMenu()" (clickOutside)="closeMenu()">
```